# QToolBar in MDI child

Tags: qt, mdi, qtgui, qtoolbar

I've got an MDI application where I'd like to create the movable toolbars in the MDI children. Adding a toolbar to the MDI children's layout makes it unmovable. Making the MDI child a subclass of the `QMainWindow` allows adding nice movable toolbars to it<del>, but breaks the MDI window switching (the main windows' title updates weird, all the MDI children appear as active at once and don't switch in z-order when non maximized)</del>.
So I'd like to know, is there any kind of a toolbar placeholder widget I can add to my MDI child to be able to drop toolbars to it, or how can I create one? Or is there any other way of creating fully functional toolbars on the non-QMainWindow widgets?

Comment: Turns out that subclassing `QMainWindow` to make an MDI child or inserting it as a widget to a QMdiSubWindow works OK and can be used to add movable toolbars (with some limitations). The weird behavior I was getting was caused by the `setFocus()` call in the MDI child's constructor.